# Firebase deploy issue while the website working fine locally

Tags: firebase, deployment

I have faced an error when deploying the website using Firebase deployment: component auth has not been registered yet. The project is working fine locally Are there any hints for help on this?  you can check the image
[image]

Tried to fix the firebase deployment error